# VS and SSMS Crashing

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, crash

I'm not very expert on SQL, and I would ask your support.

I have a SQL Server 2016 std

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU13) (KB4549825) - 13.0.5820.21 (X64)
> May 22 2020 07:24:35   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard
> Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build
> 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

with Microsoft SQL Managed Studio 18

```
SQL Server Management Studio                        15.0.18338.0 
SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)                 16.100.41011.9 
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools            15.0.19205.0 
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)             10.0.14393.0 
Microsoft MSXML                                     3.0 6.0  
Microsoft .NET Framework                            4.0.30319.42000 
Operating System                                    10.0.14393
```

and Microsoft SQL Management Studio 16 (installed for Integration Service Compatibility)

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      13.0.16106.4
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                    13.0.1700.441
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     10.0.14393.0
Microsoft MSXML                                             3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                                 9.11.14393.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                                    4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                                            6.3.14393
```

installed on Windows Server 2016 Std (VM on Microsoft Hyper-V with 80 GB RAM and 8 vCPU).

The users received a crash system
[image]

[image]

I cancelled the folder:

> C:\Users<user profile>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\SQL Server Management
> Studio\

But the problem was not solved.

Another problem from the users is:

[image]

In the Windows Application Events viewer log I see these:

> The COM+ Event System failed to fire the Logoff method on event class
> {D5978630-5B9F-11D1-8DD2-00AA004ABD5E} for publisher  and subscriber .
> The display name of the subscription is "Visual Studio ISensLogon
> Subscription". The HRESULT was 8001010a.

[image]

and these:

> Application 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe' (pid 24456) cannot be restarted - Application SID does not match Conductor SID..

[image]

In the Windows System Events viewer I see this:

> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local
> Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID
> {8D8F4F83-3594-4F07-8369-FC3C3CAE4919}  and APPID
> {F72671A9-012C-4725-9D2F-2A4D32D65169}  to the user NT
> AUTHORITY\SYSTEM SID (S-1-5-18) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC)
> running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable).
> This security permission can be modified using the Component Services
> administrative tool.

[image]

What I can check to resolve my problems?
Thanks for the support
Marco

Comment: No idea.  But I would install the latest version of those tools.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Hi David, thank you so much for your reply. I have the last version for SSMS, but it crash.